# How to get the value of list box on my web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, listbox

`<asp:ListBox ID="lst_grpmembers" DataValueField="FirstName" SelectionMode="Multiple"  runat="server"></asp:ListBox>`

I am doing databind to the list box above, I am binding userid and Firstname and only displaying first name in the list box.

```
  public void BindAddedMembers(int grpid)
      {
          DataSet ds = new DataSet();
          int newOrgID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uOrgID"].ToString());
          string userQuery = "SELECT tbl_User.userid,   FirstName FROM tbl_user INNER JOIN tbl_usergroups on tbl_user.UserID = tbl_usergroups.UserID WHERE (tbl_usergroups.groupID =@GroupID And (tbl_user.UserActive='Yes' or tbl_user.UserActive='InActive')) order by tbl_user.Firstname asc";
          MySqlParameter[] para = new MySqlParameter[1];
          para[0] = new MySqlParameter("@GroupID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
          para[0].Value = grpid;
          ds = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, userQuery, para);
          lst_grpmembers.DataSource = ds;
          lst_grpmembers.DataBind();
      }
```

There is a button in the page called update and when this is clicked I want to get the userid of each item in the list box, How can I get it. using the for loop I get the names of each item but not the user id of each item, how can I get the user id

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    foreach (ListItem li in lst_grpmembers.Items)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the `userid` to the `Value` of the `ListItem` and the `FirstName` to the `Text` of the `ListItem`

e.g.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lst_grpmembers" DataValueField="userid" DataTextField="FirstName" SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

Then in your code you can use

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string userid = '';
    string FirstName = '';
    foreach (ListItem li in lst_grpmembers.Items)
    {
         userid = li.Value;
         FirstName = li.Text;
    }
}
```

**edit**
This will expose your userid to anyone who sees this dropdown, and you might not want this. If you do not want to expose the userid to anyone, then this is not the solution for you.